# HTML list won't update immediatly

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have an Angular app that fetches places from a text request to Google Places API. Here it how it looks like:

```
this.placesService.textSearch(request, (results, placeStatus) => {
  if (placeStatus === google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
    for (let i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
      const place = results[i];
      const photo = results[i].photos[0].getUrl({ 'maxWidth': 150, 'maxHeight': 150 })
      this.getDistance(new google.maps.LatLng(place.geometry.location.lat(), place.geometry.location.lng()), (result, status) => {
        if (status === google.maps.DistanceMatrixElementStatus.OK) {
          const distance: string = result.rows[0].elements[0].distance.text;
          const duration: string = result.rows[0].elements[0].duration.text;
          this.places.push(new Place(photo, place.name, place.formatted_address, distance, duration));
        }
      });
      if (i === 4) {
        break;
      }
    }
  }
  console.log(this.places);
```

As you can see. I log the places `Array` at the end of the process. It displays correct informations.
However, it doesn't update my front as fast as the `console.log`. Here is my template:

```
<ol class="nearby-places">
  <div *ngFor="let place of places; let i = index;">
    <li class="card">
      <figure>
        <img src="{{place.icon}}" />
      </figure>
      <div class="info-container">
        <div>
          <div class="name">
            <p>{{place.name}}</p>
          </div>
          <div class="address">
            <p>{{place.address}}</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="list-nb">
          <h2>
            {{i+1}}
          </h2>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <hr *ngIf="i+1 !== places.length">
  </div>
</ol>
```

it takes 10 seconds before displaying the results.

Is there a way to say to refresh right away?

Comment: You're launching a series of asynchronous calls that have not finished executing by the time you print out your `console.log(this.places)`. Add a log statement directly after your `push()` command and you should be able to verify that.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen I tried and It prints instantly, so that's not the problem

Comment: You added log statements inside your callback function (the callback from `getDistance()`), all 5 of them print instantly, yet your view is not updated?

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen exactly!

Comment: How is your component declared? Ar you using `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush`?

Comment: @Oscar Paz My component is sometimes a map sometimes a list of places. I switch between them. Here is the full component code: https://pastebin.com/LznBihFW
I tried adding the `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` command it just didn't refresh at all

Comment: Umh, I don't know how the Google Maps API is internally, but maybe the problem is that the component does not know when the calls to Google MAps end, so it updates only when something else happens that triggers change detection

Comment: Try using the `ChangeDetector`. Just add a new parameter to the constructor of type `ChangeDetectorRef`, save it in a property (this.changeDetector), and then, after `this.places.push` call `this.changeDetector.markForCheck()`. It should work this way.

Comment: It still doesn't work... my constructor : `constructor(private _changeDetector: ChangeDetectorRef) { }` and just calling `this.changeDetector.markForCheck()` where I log data

Comment: I belive that your issue here is that you are using a callback that is out of angular context. Try to inject NgZone to your component and inside of the `textSearch` callback wrap all the code with `this.ngZone.run(() => { /*your code here*/});`

Comment: Are you clearing your `this.places` Array somewhere by assigning new Array? 
    `this.places = [];` ? If so don't do that other than initialization. For clearing use `this.places.length = 0`, it will clear the array and maintain the same reference of the Array Object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing to note here is that in order to ngFor directive update the dom, you need to **make a copy** of your places array. If you don't make a copy, ngFor doesn't know that the array have changed. You can do like this (look at the final of the function):

```
this.placesService.textSearch(request, (results, placeStatus) => {
  if (placeStatus === google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
   for (let i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
    const place = results[i];
    const photo = results[i].photos[0].getUrl({ 'maxWidth': 150, 'maxHeight': 150 })
    this.getDistance(new google.maps.LatLng(place.geometry.location.lat(), place.geometry.location.lng()), (result, status) => {
    if (status === google.maps.DistanceMatrixElementStatus.OK) {
      const distance: string = result.rows[0].elements[0].distance.text;
      const duration: string = result.rows[0].elements[0].duration.text;
      this.places.push(new Place(photo, place.name, place.formatted_address, distance, duration));
    }
  });
     if (i === 4) {
      break;
     }
   }
  }
  console.log(this.places);
  // HERE make a copy!!
  this.places = this.places.slice();
}
```

If with that code the ngFor is still not reflecting the new array on the dom, it will say that your request or wathever that finishes with you updating the array, is outside the zone. If this happens, you can **detectChanges** manually or run inside the zone and perform a **markForCheck**(). Both options are valid depending on your goals. You can easily find more information about that on the web.
Here will be the detectChanges example:

```
// In your constructor..
constructor(private cd: ChangeDetectorRef) {..}

// In your func
this.placesService.textSearch(request, (results, placeStatus) => {
  if (placeStatus === google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
  for (let i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
  const place = results[i];
  const photo = results[i].photos[0].getUrl({ 'maxWidth': 150, 'maxHeight': 150 })
  this.getDistance(new google.maps.LatLng(place.geometry.location.lat(), place.geometry.location.lng()), (result, status) => {
    if (status === google.maps.DistanceMatrixElementStatus.OK) {
      const distance: string = result.rows[0].elements[0].distance.text;
      const duration: string = result.rows[0].elements[0].duration.text;
      this.places.push(new Place(photo, place.name, place.formatted_address, distance, duration));
    }
  });
  if (i === 4) {
    break;
  }
}
}
console.log(this.places);
// HERE make a copy!!
this.places = this.places.slice();
// and detect changes manually
this.cd.detectChanges();

}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Ok, weirdly enough, it only works when I add multiple `detectChanges()` in every scope